# Elasticsearch compatiblity with Springboot 3.0.7

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, spring-data-commons

While upgrading our projet from spring-boot **3.0.2** to **3.0.7**, I'm facing a problem with Elasticsearch

I suspect that is related to the version of Elasticsearch server we use that is not compatible with SB **3.0.7**.

When I uploaded to v7.10.1 of elasticsearch server, it worked without problem
When I changed the docker image to use elasticsearch v6.8.23, it also worked

So, I don't khow if it is really a problem of compatibilty between the version of spring boot and elasticsearch server/client versions (or anything else)

```
implementation  group: 'org.elasticsearch.client',  name: 'elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client',   version: **'6.8.23'**
implementation  group: 'org.elasticsearch',         name: 'elasticsearch', version: **'6.8.23'**
**implementation  group: 'org.springframework.data',  name: 'spring-data-commons'**
```

We are **using spring-data-commons** instead of **spring-data-elasticsearch**

We are using this docker-compose.yml file for tests

```
version: "2"

services:
  elasticsearch:
   ** image: elasticsearch:7.10.1**
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
```

Here is the error:

```
Caused by: ElasticsearchException[Error while creating index usedcars_vehicle_20230616_102841973_fr_fr]; nested: IOException[listener timeout after waiting for [90000] ms];
    at com.renault.wired.elasticsearch.rest.repository.IndicesRepositoryImpl.createIndex(IndicesRepositoryImpl.java:102)
    at com.renault.wired.elasticsearch.rest.repository.IndicesRepositoryImpl.createNextIndex(IndicesRepositoryImpl.java:111)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:288)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy65.createNextIndex(Unknown Source)
    at com.renault.wired.elasticsearch.rest.init.ElasticsearchPopulator.populate(ElasticsearchPopulator.java:42)
    at com.renault.wired.elasticsearch.rest.init.ElasticsearchRepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(ElasticsearchRepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean.java:38)
    at com.renault.wired.elasticsearch.rest.init.ElasticsearchRepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(ElasticsearchRepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean.java:20)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:437)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:370)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:611)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1388)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:545)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:118)
    ... 72 more
```